# GWT dev mode performance problems?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm working on a small GWT project in Intellij using their built-in support.  Dev mode functions, but the performance is really spotty, and I can only reload the app a handful of times before getting OutOfMemoryError (using -Xmx512M).

What should I be able to expect out of dev mode?  Do others experience consistent reload times and long running processes?

I'm running GWT 2.2 with IDEA 10.0.3.  My app is small, but I do include several other modules like Activity, Place, Resources, Guava Collect + Base, UiBinder, Gin Inject, etc.  I believe the performance problems started before many of these dependencies were added, though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to increase PermGen memory size via: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m. It should help. I had the same problem, analyzed what's becoming exhausted with Visual VM and it turned out that PermGen was the problem. Of course -Xmx also helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip.  I should have specified -- it is indeed  PermGen that's filling up.  I'll try that flag for a while and see where I get.

Comment: Wow, huge improvement.  Thanks!